# Primefaces CKeditor won't render

Tags: jsf, primefaces, ckeditor, primefaces-extensions

I'm attempting to use Primefaces extensions CKeditor and am not able to get it to work. All of the similar questions on SO were caused by not including resource-ckeditor, I have done that. I get a javascript error in the browser, that is likely related. The below code renders a size adjustable text area box only.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:pe="http://primefaces.org/ui/extensions"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core">
    <h:head>
        <title>Facelet Title</title>
    </h:head>
    <f:view>
    <h:body>
        <h:form>
        <pe:ckEditor id="editor" value="Test">  
        </pe:ckEditor>
        </h:form>
    </h:body>
    </f:view>
</html>
```

This is my POM

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
            <version>6.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces.extensions</groupId>
            <artifactId>primefaces-extensions</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces.extensions</groupId>
            <artifactId>resources-ckeditor</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

This is the error I get in the browser

```
test.xhtml:8 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
```

And this is the relevant HTML code outputted to the browser

```
<h:inputText></h:inputText><textarea id="editor" name="editor">test</textarea><script id="editor_s" type="text/javascript">$(function(){PrimeFaces.cw("ExtCKEditor","widget_editor",{id:"editor",height:"200px",width:"600px",readOnly:false,advancedContentFilter:true});});</script>
```

I'm completely baffled to why this is not working, it seems like everything is right.

Comment: `$ is not defined` means you may have forgotten to import an appropriate jQuery library.

Comment: @Tiny, thanks - that must mean JSF or Primefaces is broken somewhere since I think those frameworks are supposed to handle that. Either that or Maven is not downloading required dependencies maybe?

Answer (score 1):

I believe there must be at least 1 Primefaces component on the page in order to trigger Primefaces to inject the resources (js, css) to the head.

Try putting something in there, for example

```
<p:outputLabel style="display:none"/>
```

and add the namespace (`xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"`) too.

Comment: Thanks for the response, was definitely worth a shot, but no love